# Finding product version using upgrade code using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi, upgrade, windows-update

I have to update some products (MSI) using their [upgrade codes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pusu/2009/06/10/what-are-upgrade-product-and-package-codes-used-for/), I have list of all such products' upgrade codes. Now to push updates I need to compare every product's version.

How to find the product version in such scenarios?

Like:

```
gwmi win32_product | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "name"}
```

But this uses the name, I would like to find the version using the upgrade code only.

Comment: how are the version and upgrade codes connected? how would one use the upgrade code to identify the product?

Comment: I am very new to powershell and these updates. What I was thinking is that for every product (in my case MSI) there will be one upgrade code (and product, package code as well). Can I somehow use that upgrade code and know the product version. I am trying to do it using WQL.
Please suggest if there is any other way to find product version.

Comment: i don't know what a "package code" or an "upgrade code" _is_. [*blush*] therefore, i can't make even the most vague of guesses as to how to use such to find an installed application. _please_, would you kindly explain what you are talking about?

Comment: Hi Marc,
Thanks for the edit :)
@Lee please "see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pusu/2009/06/10/what-are-upgrade-product-and-package-codes-used-for/"

Comment: I think this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637094/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-msi-file

Comment: @AbbyJangir - thanks for the info! [*grin*] ///// it looks like monotero has answered your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish what you're looking for in PowerShell is by using the following WMI query to grab packages that belong to an UpgradeCode family.

```
$UpgradeCode = '{AA783A14-A7A3-3D33-95F0-9A351D530011}'
$ProductGUIDs = @(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Property | Where-Object {$_.Property -eq 'UpgradeCode' -and $_.value -eq $UpgradeCode}).ProductCode

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$ProductGUIDs -Contains $_.IdentifyingNumber}
```

The only downside to this it that both the Win32_Property and Win32_Product classes are slow, if time isn't a huge factor you can use that.  If you need faster performance you can get similar information from the registry like this

```
function Decode-GUID {
    param( [string]$GUID )
    $GUIDSections = @( 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ) 
    $Position = 0
    $result = @()

    ForEach($GUIDSection In $GUIDSections)
    { $arr = $GUID.SubString($Position, $GUIDSection) -split ""; 
    [array]::Reverse($arr);
    $result = $result +($arr -join '').replace(' ',''); 
    $Position += $GUIDSection } 
    return "{$(($result -join '').Insert(8,'-').Insert(13, '-').Insert(18, '-').Insert(23, '-'))}"
}

function Encode-GUID {
    param( [string]$GUID )
    $GUID = $GUID -creplace '[^0-F]'
    $GUIDSections = @( 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ) 

    $Position = 0
    $result = ""

    ForEach($GUIDSection In $GUIDSections)
    { $arr = $GUID.substring($Position, $GUIDSection) -split ""; 
    [array]::Reverse($arr);
    $result = $result + ($arr -join '').replace(' ',''); 
    $Position += $GUIDSection } 
    return $result
}

function Get-Bitness {
    param( [string]$Location )
    if([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem){
        if($_.PSPath -match '\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node'){
            return '32'
            }else{
            return '64'
            }
    } else {
        Return '32'
    }

}

#Enter the UpgradeCode here
$UpgradeCode = Encode-GUID "{AA783A14-A7A3-3D33-95F0-9A351D530011}"

$ProductGUIDs = (Get-Item HKLM:"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UpgradeCodes\$UpgradeCode", HKLM:"SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\UpgradeCodes\$UpgradeCode").Property |
    Select-Object -Unique |
    ForEach-Object {Decode-GUID $_}

Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
    Where-Object {$ProductGUIDs -contains $_.PSChildName} |
    Get-ItemProperty |
    Select-Object -Property @{Name='PackageCode';Expression={$_.PSChildName}}, DisplayName, Publisher, DisplayVersion, InstallDate, PSParentPath, @{Name='Bitness';Expression={Get-Bitness $_.PSPath}}
```

In the registry the GUIDs used in the "Installer" sections are encoded to match the way C++ would natively use them. The Decode and Encode functions in the example above are based on the technique used in this [Roger Zander blog post](http://rzander.azurewebsites.net/msi-upgradecode-as-detection-method-in-cm12-2/).  Please excuse the messiness of some of the code, if you need any part of this explained please let me know.  Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for the reply.
Time is a prime concern to me.
For your second suggestion, how do I know if the package is for 32 bit or 64 bit so the path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"  will be different for 32bit packages.

Comment: Hey @AbbyJangir I've just added an addition function and property to give PS ParentPath and Bitness.  Does that get you all the information you need?

Comment: Hi @Paul G,
Thank you for your time. It works for :) :)