# How to read product code from an msi package?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-installer

I want to get the product code from an msi file before installing it. I need it to remove the other version of a product if it's already installed on my computer. I mean I want to prevent an error 1638 ("Another version of this product already exists...") and to delete it manually in my code. I'm using c++.
So I want to get the product code from the msi file that is about to install and using this product code remove the existing version of the product and install a new one. But  when I'm trying to open an msi file to get it's handle using

`MsiOpenPackage(msiPackagePath, &d_handle);`

I get an error 1638. So I can not open an msi file and can not get a product code from it. My question: is it possible to get a product code from msi file not opening it with `MsiOpenPackage`? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Major upgrades are generally implemented via the Upgrade code. It should match between the two MSI versions. You author the [Upgrade table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/upgrade-table) with details on how you want the upgrade to work, and then the uninstall of the previous versions happens by built-in MSI mechanisms. [Find product code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29937568/129130). [Find upgrade code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46637094/129130). [**Debugging failed major upgrades**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991527/129130).

Comment: I have samples for code access to the MSI, but don't have time to locate it right now. Do you really need it? Why are you going via C++? Are you invoking install from an application?

Answer (score 0):

My colleague has just solved a problem. We used a function `MsiOpenPackageEx` and passed a flag `MSIOPENPACKAGEFLAGS_IGNOREMACHINESTATE` to ignore the computer state and return a handle anyway.

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve this when you can use a major upgrade and author the upgrade table to uninstall the previous version? What tool are you using to make the MSI?